# How to add a field to an existing model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I would like to extend and override the fields existing in the User model, which is found in "django.contrib.auth.models" (The model is already created). I first attempted to create a **Foreign-Key** and a **One-to-One relationship** between the **User model**, and a **Client model** (in which I added the extra fields), but I don't think it is good practice. How could I directly add and override fields within the User model and not have to create another class model to extend it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Clients(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
#client = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
cell = models.PositiveIntegerField (blank=False)
address = models.CharField(default = "Sandton, JHB", blank = False, max_length=132)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    pass
```

Now in your settings.py file, add the following line

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "module.file.CustomUSer"
```